# How to create a batch script that restarts a executable after it is closed?

Tags: batch-file, restart

I want to create a batch file that can detect an executable is running or not and if not, it should start it immediately after the executable is closed.
I tried wait command but it doesn't seems to work as I wanted, like when I type:

```
@echo off
:Restart
start "SY" /wait "C:\Program Files (x86)\SY.exe"
goto Restart
```

It starts my executable program and not let it close, but when the executable is minimized and restored, then it closes very easily when close button is clicked.
Then it shows a message in the command window: ^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?

But nothing like that happens when I try the same batch code for notepad executable:

```
@echo off
:Restart
start "Edit Text" /wait "%windir%\Notepad.exe"
goto Restart
```

The notepad window never close, even by minimizing and restoring then clicking close, it does not close.
So I want the results for my executable to be the same as the results for the notepad executable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.... Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: What app type is your `C:\Program Files (x86)\SY.exe` ? A console app, windows gui or windows UWP? What about running the program without start?

Answer (score 0):

you can check if your .EXE is running with `takslist`. If it isn't running (`||`) then just start it. Put a loop around and you're done:

```
:loop
tasklist |findstr /ibc:"SY.EXE" || "C:\Program Files (x86)\SY.exe"
timeout 1
goto :loop
```